# When should a period be used after $ in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I am a beginner in JQuery.

**When should the dot after $ be used?**

`$.trim(str)` and not `$trim(str)`?

And some cases without point: `$(document).ready`, but not `$.(document).ready`?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: the dollar sign will generally be immediately followed either by parenthesis, or by a dot and a method name. Of course, you should definitely try to learn the JavaScript language so you understand what all the dots and parentheses really mean :)

Answer (score 19):

In jQuery, `$` is a variable name, like `foo` or `bar`, which references the global jQuery object. If you want to access a property on the jQuery object, then you use the dot. These are basically the same:

```
$.property
jQuery.property
```

(Since `$` is a variable like any other, it is possible for you to set it to anything you like. This might happen if you were to include the [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) library after including the jQuery library, which would leave you with `$` pointing to an alias of the `document.getElementById` function.)

The jQuery object happens to also be a function, so you can call that function the same as you would call any other function:

```
$(arguments)
alert("arguments!")
```

On the other hand, `$trim` is just another global variable, like `$` or `location`, which could be a function you defined yourself:

```
var $trim = function(arguments) {
    return "foo";
};

$trim(str)
```

Answer (score 18):

I don't believe you have a choice, only one syntax is correct and will actually work. The `$` symbol is nothing more than a shorthand notation for the `jQuery` function, so when you write:

```
$('some selector')
```

You are calling a function, called `jQuery`, and passing in a string, or in your case, you're passing in the `document` object.

When it comes to invoking a method, such as a helper method like trim, you will need to use the following syntax, either `jQuery.trim()` or `$.trim()`. It's easy to check yourself, just try this out:

```
typeof($.trim) //returns "function"
typeof($trim) //returns "undefined"
```

Comment: …and the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator) operator doesn't need parentheses, nor a dot. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

When you are accessing the static method of jQuery that isn't available in the prototype of say, a DOM element. `trim` is a static method exposed by the API.

There is no `$.fn.trim` and we can't reliably rely on `String.prototype.trim` since the methods can differ.

Regarding `$trim` that's not defined. The `trim` is a method of `$` which is jQuery. You can do either `$['trim']` or `$.trim`, and that should be the only way to access it.

Answer (score 2):

The `$.foo` syntax means that `$` is being treated as an object with a field called `foo`, which is typically a function you're calling. So this is really nothing different to a standalone function called `foo` - it's just prefixed with `$.` to distinguish it from any other function and associate it with the jQuery library.

When you use `$(something).foo` then you're passing `something` to the jQuery function, and the result depends on what you're passing (could be a selector to find an existing object, or it could be a scrap of HTML to build a new object, or it could be a function to be registered to run on page load). In any case, you're then calling `foo` on the resulting returned object, which may be applied to several DOM objects if the selector you passed identifies a class, for example.

The first syntax is used when the jQuery function operates on something other than DOM objects (parts of the HTML page). For example, a string (`$.trim`), or an array (`$.each`). Those aren't elements of the page, they're just pure data in JavaScript.

The second syntax is used when operating on DOM elements - you use `$(something)` to make a jQuery object, which is a wrapper around zero or more DOM elements. Then you call functions on the returned wrapper to conveniently manipulate the objects it wraps.